# UPDATE Query with IF Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a MySQL query with an `IF` statement. Here is a database schema:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_db;
USE my_db;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS if_table(
    id INTEGER unsigned,
    field_1 INTEGER unsigned,
    field_2 INTEGER unsigned,
    field_3 INTEGER unsigned,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

How do I write an `UPDATE` query which corresponds to next pseudo code?

```
if field_2 equals 0 then field_1 = field_1 + 1
else field_3 = field_3 + 2 
where id == 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Try this in-line `IF` statement</strike>

```
SELECT IF(field_2 = 0, field_1 + 1, field_3 + 2) AS `Result`
FROM tableName
WHERE ID = 1
```

or if you want to update the value,

```
UPDATE tableName
SET field_1 = IF(field_2 = 0, field_1 + 1, field_1),  
    field_3 = IF(field_2 = 0, field_3, field_3 + 2)
WHERE ID = 1
```

Comment: but it does not modify field of the table

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with two query.

```
UPDATE table_name SET field_1 = field_1 + 1 WHERE id = 1 AND field_2 = 0;
UPDATE table_name SET field_3 = field_3 + 2 WHERE id = 1 AND field_2 != 0;
```

If you want only one query, then

```
UPDATE table_name
SET field_1 = IF(field_2 = 0, field_1 + 1, field_1),
SET field_3 = IF(field_2 = 0, field_3, field_3 + 2),
WHERE ID = 1
```

Comment: in my case, 3rd party can change database field, so if I use two queries then somebody can change field in time between executing these two queries.

Comment: @xdazz is it a typo on `SET field_3 =...`?